# Spring Boot: how download and upload a file from a source to a destination via a RESTful API

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, download, upload

I'd like to discuss with you about the best approach to implement this scenario in Spring Boot.

1. My app needs to download a file from a source via RESTful API
2. My app will upload the file in a destination via RESTful API

So, my app is in middle of two application (sorce and destination) and has to move the file from source to destination.

What is the best approach to achieve this scenario to save memory and avoid OOM?

Comment: The general answer is: use streams. If you're having a specifc issue, share some code

Comment: So do you mean open a stream from source and writes in the destination stream, will it save memory?

Comment: Yes, the idea behind a stream is that it doesn't stay in memory (aside from some buffers).

Comment: Do you think that using Apache Camel I can improve it?

Comment: I'd assume a standard HTTP client already has this functionality, and you don't need anything fancy.

Comment: Thank Evert, I wanted to make sure to avoid an OOM or too CPU time consuming

Comment: Yes I've read your question.